Estoy estudiando sql, me plantean el siguiente problema
Dada las tablas empleados y departamentos que vimos previamente, escribe una consulta que devuelva todos los registros coincidentes y no coincidentes entre las tablas empleados y departamentos.
Adjunto las tablas 
Les comparto mi respuesta pues he probado de diferentes maneras y aun no consigo pasar el ejercicio:
SELECT empleados.id_empleado, empleados.nombre, 
empleados.id_departamento, departamentos.departamento 
FROM empleados 
LEFT JOIN departamentos 
    ON empleados.id_departamento = departamentos.id_departamento 
UNION 
SELECT empleados.id_empleado, empleados.nombre, 
empleados.id_departamento, departamentos.departamento 
FROM departamentos 
LEFT JOIN empleados 
    ON empleados.id_departamento = departamentos.id_departamento;


¿Y qué mensaje de error recibes? ¿Te falta algún dato? ¿Te sale algún dato duplicado?

¿Qué es un registro "no coincidente"? ¿Un registro ¿de dónde? que no coincide ¿con qué? ?.

¿Cuál es el output que esperas? Puedes editar tu pregunta y agregar más información

¿Por qué escribes una emulación de un FULL OUTER JOIN? Es una cosa que tenemos que hacer si usamos un DBMS que no soporta FULL OUTER JOIN. Pero SQLite lo hace.

Y por favor no uses imagenes para mostrar los datos. Usa texto formateado en vez.

Con union puedes tener resultados inesperados debido al uso de UNION y JOIN en ambas direcciones, para encontrar los coincidentes y no coincidentes te recomiendo usar "FULL OUTER JOIN".
SELECT 
    E.id_empleado, 
    E.nombre AS nombre_empleado, 
    E.id_departamento, 
    D.nombre AS nombre_departamento
FROM 
    empleados E
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    departamentos D
ON 
    E.id_departamento = D.id_departamento;

En la consulta que usas, la salida sería casi idéntica a la del FULL OUTER JOIN, pero con la precaución de que el UNION elimina duplicados, lo que podría afectar ligeramente el resultado dependiendo de los datos específicos.
En el caso de sqlite que no soporta FULL OUTHER JOIN ni RIGHT JOIN puedes hacer.
SELECT 
    E.id_empleado, 
    E.nombre AS nombre_empleado, 
    E.id_departamento, 
    D.nombre AS nombre_departamento
FROM 
    empleados E
LEFT JOIN 
    departamentos D
ON 
    E.id_departamento = D.id_departamento

UNION

SELECT 
    E.id_empleado, 
    E.nombre AS nombre_empleado, 
    E.id_departamento, 
    D.nombre AS nombre_departamento
FROM 
    departamentos D
LEFT JOIN 
    empleados E
ON 
    E.id_departamento = D.id_departamento
WHERE 
    E.id_empleado IS NULL;

La idea es como en tu planteamiento, obtener todas las coincidencias en ambos sentidos, pero en el segundo LEFT JOIN obtener solo las que tienen el id empleado como NULL para evitar los duplicados.

No puedo usar FULL OUTER JOIN pues el curso es basado en SQLite y no lo admite, tampoco el RIGHT JOIN, que es la otra solucion que tenia, he probado de mil maneras.

Bien, edité la respuesta para sqlite. Disculpa no había leído bien tu planteamiento. Saludos

Muchas gracias, me sirvió de mucho tu ayuda, solo tuve que hacer una pequeña ,odificación para que quedar como se esperaba, error del propio curso, ya quedo listo, muchas gracias.
